# how to create propertypath for Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.Viewbox" in codebehind?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I'm trying to use WPF to learn how to animate the size of the viewbox for an opacitymask using codebehind, in xaml it's like this

```
<Storyboard>
    <RectAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="OpacityMask.Viewbox"
                   From="-1,-1,3,3" To="0.49,0.49,0.02,0.02" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
</Storyboard>
```

and it works very well. Now I am trying to do it in code behind, but I don't know what to put for the property path, I tried

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OpacityMask.ViewBoxProperty));
```

but it gives error. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [TileBrush.Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewbox.aspx) property:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(TileBrush.ViewboxProperty));
```

or

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Viewbox"));
```

You also need to set the animation target object:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, element.OpacityMask);
```

---

You may of course also set the element itself as animation target and use the same property path as in your XAML:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, element);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("OpacityMask.Viewbox"));
```